# How to customize qTip2 css?

Tags: jquery, html, css, qtip2

I am using [qTip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) on my website but have some problems with the css.

I have included the following files :

jquery.qtip.min.js
jquery.qtip.min.css

In the js file I have added the following :

```
$.each($(".tooltip"), function (i, val) {

    var theContent = $(val).html();
    $(val).qtip({
        content: {
            text: theContent
        },
        position: {
            my: "bottom left",
            at: "top right",
            viewport: $(window)
        },
        show: {
            event: false,
            ready: true
        },
        hide: {
            effect: function () { $(this).slideUp(5, function () { $(this).dequeue(); }); }
        },
        style: {
            classes: "ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-jtools"
        }
    });
});
```

So far, so good, the problem with this is that it will load the jtools theme, I need to costomize this so I extract the jtools styles from jquery.qtip.css and place it in my own css file like this :

```
.ui-tooltip-shadow {
    box-shadow:                 1px 1px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.ui-tooltip-shadow .ui-tooltip-titlebar, .ui-tooltip-shadow .ui-tooltip-content {
}




/* jQuery TOOLS Tooltip style */
.ui-tooltip-MySite{
    background: #232323;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #717171, #232323);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#717171), to(#232323));

    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    border: 2px solid rgba(241,241,241,1);

    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #333;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #333;
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px #333;
}

    /* IE Specific */
    .ui-tooltip-MySite.ui-tooltip-titlebar{
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#717171,endColorstr=#4A4A4A);
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#717171,endColorstr=#4A4A4A)";
    }
    .ui-tooltip-MySite.ui-tooltip-content{
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4A4A4A,endColorstr=#232323);
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4A4A4A,endColorstr=#232323)";
    }

    .ui-tooltip-MySite.ui-tooltip-titlebar,
    .ui-tooltip-MySite.ui-tooltip-content{
        background: transparent;
        color: white;
        border: 0 dashed transparent;
    }

    .ui-tooltip-MySite.ui-tooltip-icon{
        border-color: #555;
    }

    .ui-tooltip-MySite.ui-tooltip-titlebar .ui-state-hover{
        border-color: #333;
    }
```

In the declaration of the tooltip I change :

```
classes: "ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-jtools"
```

to

```
classes: "ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-MySite"
```

The problem is that the content do still get the yellow default color? why?

Comment: Have you forgot to add your class in `style: {classes: "ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-jtools"}` or do you add your own class with other way ?

Comment: @Corum > ui-tooltip-MySite is my class and this is set as you can see last in my post. I simple switch -jtools to -MySite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in my implemenation was that the $.each($(".tooltip"), function (i, val) had to be within $(document).ready(function ().

Answer (score 1):

If you use this code you can apply CSS styling as if it were a div

```
this.tooltip = function(){  
/* CONFIG */        
    xOffset = 10;
    yOffset = 20;       
    // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
    // you might want to adjust to get the right result     
/* END CONFIG */        
$("img.tooltip").hover(function(e){                                           
    this.t = this.title;
    this.title = "";                                      
    $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>"+ this.t +"</p>");
    $("#tooltip")
        .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
        .fadeIn("fast");        
},
function(){
    this.title = this.t;        
    $("#tooltip").remove();
}); 
$("img.tooltip").mousemove(function(e){
    $("#tooltip")
        .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    });         
};
```

[Live example here](http://jsfiddle.net/VcGae/)

Comment: Thanks, But I dont get it? Why is it not enouth to point out the class that the tip should use as style? I am setting classes: "ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-MySite" and this should mean that it uses that class instead. If I switch to classes: "ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-jtools" I can see that it is using the correct style. I do however need to customize this to my site so thats why I have copied the classes and then done some minor changes to them. The problem is that class is never used?

Comment: @SnowJim See this jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/VcGae/). It is a tiny little thing that is very easy to use. You can apply styling as you like, and you need not worry about any of the other long classes.

Comment: This is a really bad answer. OP asked about how to style a qtip tooltip. Not how you would implement a tooltip yourself.